# Cannot knit Markdown doc using the {flair} package - "Could not find function viewer"

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

I'm trying out the flair package within a markdown document, and I'm having trouble knitting a document as shown in the [package's announcement page](https://education.rstudio.com/blog/2020/05/flair/). Here's a basic .Rmd example using code from that page:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(readr)
library(flair)
baby_names <- read_delim("https://education.rstudio.com/blog/2020/05/flair/kellys_ca.txt", delim = " ")
```

```{r geoms, include=FALSE}
baby_names %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Count, fill = Gender)) +
  geom_col()

baby_names %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Count, color = Gender)) +
  geom_line()
```

```{r echo=FALSE}
decorate("geoms") %>%
  flair("_col") %>%
  flair("fill = ") %>%
  flair("_line") %>%
  flair("color = ")
```
````

This fails to knit, giving me this error:

> Error in viewer(htmlFile) : could not find function "viewer" Calls:  ... knit_print.default -> normal_print -> print -> print.with_flair

I have tried knitting without preview without success either. I'm not entirely certain where the "viewer" function is coming from, or why it's being utilized.

EDIT: Will keep it open for now, but it seems to be a bug: https://github.com/kbodwin/flair/issues/13